# why no hair growth in the non vertex region

Tags: particles, hair

With the hair particles i have long hairs. With the vertex paint i have mark the region and inverted the selection to fix the hair grown in region. The hairs are in the region but not in all faces.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I8gdkk91xY7fadmwKtpa1S9SOE1-Z8nA)

**Vertex group**

[image]

**Result** (No hairs in the red regions)

[image]

**Settings**

[image]     [image]

[image]     [image]

Any suggestion why no hair growth in the regions. Thanks

Comment: Emit from 'volume' instead of 'faces', I presume.

Comment: @lemon i tried with the faces also still no hairs . https://imgur.com/gallery/IILlmTP

Comment: Can you upload a blend with a part of it?

Comment: @lemon plz check the link in the question.

Comment: Is it supposed to be like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHuu7.jpg